# Can a git repository have N working trees

Tags: libgit2

I try to write a file store based on `libgit2`.
Software snapshots should be saved as branches `mysoftware` and specific versions committed and tagged. Then later I want to checkout the tags to different directories.

When looking at `git_checkout_tree`, it seems like there is only one working tree for a repository and thus it does not even seem possible to checkout multiple working trees concurrently.
Is this correct!?

**EDIT:**

Additionally, I would like for this thing to work on Windows without the need for cygwin!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple working directories with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/multiple-working-directories-with-git)

Comment: Actually it turned out that using a bare repository was sufficient in my case, since I only want the repo edited by my libgit2 implementation. And utilizing `Tree` and `Index`, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git_checkout_opts` structure in `libgit2` contains a `target_directory` option that will allow `git_checkout_tree()` to write to a different directory instead of using the default working tree for the repository. This would allow you to custom build a solution with libgit2 that maintained multiple checked out copies.

Without using that option, a `libgit2` `git_repository` object expects there will be just one working directory and looks to the `core.worktree` config option if it isn't the "natural" working directory for the repository.

The `git-new-workdir` tricks with symlinks in the `.git` directory don't work great with `libgit2` right now, I'm afraid, and particularly doesn't work well on Windows.  I'd love to see this addressed, but it isn't too high on my priority list.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't support this natively, but you can use [git-new-workdir](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/) to do it.

Comment: See my question edit. I do not want an external script but be self contained.

Comment: Then, no, as I stated, Git doesn't support this natively. You'll have to clone a second copy of the repository.